# Troubleshoot - Ambiguous column name xyz

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I run the following query and I get the ambiguous error. Why is it happening ?

```
select * 
from dbo.tableA as table1, dbo.tableZ as table2
where (columnB = dbo.tableZ.columnB)
```

> Ambiguous column name columnB

tableA also has a column named columnB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tables have a `columnB` but the first part of your condition doesn't specify from which table to use `columnB`.

Change it to this:

```
select * 
from dbo.tableA as table1, dbo.tableZ as table2
where (table1.columnB = table2.columnB)
```

Comment: One small thing - If I declare the aliases, but use the fully qualified column names instead in my WHERE, I get error - the multi part identifier Xyz could not be bound. Why ?

Comment: @sequel.learner: Because the name of the table in the context of your query is that of the alias you specified. As soon as you specify an alias, the original table name is no longer known.

Comment: Can your/my SQL be considered a join because it is using two tables ? If yes, how does one justify it ?

Comment: @sequel.learner: It's an old style join. You would usually write it using `INNER JOIN` nowadays, just like christian showed it. However, I don't quite get what you mean when you ask how to "justify" it.

Comment: @sequel.learner: when you use a join, you want the results from n tables based on the join clause, one of the tables will hold a primary key, referenced in another by a foreign key - e.g. People table may have CountryId and the Country table will have Id, these would like together to get the country information for this person from the country table - instead of holding all the country information in the People table

Comment: @christiandev - so my query turns out to be a join then ?

Comment: @sequel.learner: yes, but as Daniel pointed out, it's an old style and not an ANSI standard join: take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: @christiandev - thanks for the link. I saw the answer here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join
What I did is an implicit join.

Comment: No, it's still an inner join, as you have used a WHERE clause. So, for records to be picked up, the values need to exist in both tables. If you wanted the Left table to display a record, regardless of whether the corresponding key exists in the joined table, you can use LEFT join

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the alias for the field names.  It's a good rule to reference your fields using the alias when creating joins so that others can read the SQL easier...

e.g.

```
SELECT  t1.ColA ,
        t1.ColB ,
        t2.ColA
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.FId
```

instead of...

```
SELECT  ColA ,
        ColB ,
        ColA
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.FId
```

I know the second SQL query would not parse, but it's just an example.